# How to show a Fragment in a Dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a fragment with some text and an image:

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);

        return view;  

    }

}
```

Is there any way to get it to show in a dialog?

For example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Showing a fragment in a dialog");

// Load fragment as dialog content somehow

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every dialog has `setView` method which you can create programmatically or inflate, see this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout)
You should also consider to use a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: Thanks. I changed the ContentFragment to extend DialogFragment instead of Fragment, then used setView() to display the fragment in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog is not supposed to host a fragment.

A workaround you can use is to replace dialog UI, which can be achieved by:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_content)
```

This will just change the dialog view, if you want to bind events or data to the controls inside your fragment, you need to do it after setContentView

Comment: So using setContentView() doesn't trigger any of the fragment code like in onCreateView()?

Comment: Sadly it won't. It will just inflate the view.